# UI Bezier Path changes LineWidth when screen orientation changes.

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath

So I am trying to create a simple set of axes in a custom UIView. Here's the code:

```
@IBDesignable
class GraphingView: UIView {


@IBInspectable
var axesColor : UIColor = UIColor.redColor() { didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() } }

@IBInspectable
var lineWidth : CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet{ setNeedsDisplay() } }

var origin : CGPoint{
    return convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let axesPath = UIBezierPath()
    axesPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: origin.y))
    axesPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: origin.y))
    axesPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: 0))
    axesPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: bounds.height))
    axesPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    axesColor.set()
    axesPath.stroke()

}


}
```

In portrait, this turns out fine:

[image: Portrait]

but in landscape, the vertical line is a little bit thicker:

[image: Landscape]

Can anyone help me with why that happens and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out in the end. Right now, the mode for the custom view was set at "Scale to Fill". I just had to change it to "redraw" so it would run drawRect again.

Comment: I did not expect finding a solution using SO for this, but your question and answered saved me a hastle. thanks